# Segmentation fault when pclose after fscanf

Tags: segmentation-fault, scanf, pclose

I try to get lost packets number (from ping command on raspberry) which I use for sim switching on router. I tried to do that with code at the bottom (reduced to error causing part), but when I try to free (pclose) buffer I get segmentation fault. I've tried valgrind and I got this:

Invalid read of size 4
at 0x490FBE0: fclose@@GLIBC_2.4 (iofclose.c:53)
Address 0x382e3820 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
Access not within mapped region at address 0x382E3820

I guess I'm missusing fscanf but I don't know how (I get printf result and it's correct - 4).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "params.h"
#include <pthread.h> 

void *pingOnly(void *vargp){

    FILE *cmd;
    int packetsReceived=0;
    while(1){
        cmd = popen("sudo ping 8.8.8.8 -c 4 -q","r");
        fscanf(cmd, "%[^,], %d", &packetsReceived);
        printf("%d\n", packetsReceived);
        pclose(cmd);        
        if(packetsReceived<3){
            //testSpeed();
        }
        sleep(300);
    }
    return NULL;    
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{ 
    pthread_t thread_id[3]; 
    pthread_create(&thread_id[2], NULL, pingOnly, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_id[2], NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
fscanf(cmd, "%[^,], %d", &packetsReceived);
```

which tries to read a string into `int packetsReceived` and runs off into undefined behavior, smashing the stack.  You probably meant to do

```
fscanf(cmd, "%*[^,], %d", &packetsReceived);
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I've checked that line like 10 times and didn't notice that.